# Fluentbit unable to export metrics from node_metrics_exporter input to kafka output

Tags: fluentd, fluent-bit, strimzi

Configured fluentbit daemonset in kubernetes with following data in configmap given below

```
data:
  custom_parsers.conf: |

    [PARSER]
        Name        json
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 1
        Log_Level info
        Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf
        Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/conf/custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        Health_Check On

    [INPUT]
        Name            node_exporter_metrics
        Tag             node_metrics_cpu
        Scrape_interval 2
        metrics         cpu, cpufreq, loadavg

    [OUTPUT]
        Name     stdout
        Match    node_metrics_cpu

    [OUTPUT]
        Name        kafka
        Match       node_metrics_cpu
        Brokers     example-kafka-bootstrap.fluentbit-demo.svc.cluster.local:9092
        Topics      cpu_metrics
        Format      json
```

stdout is producing the output but kafka topic is not exporting data.

Kafka cluster is created using strimzi-kafka operator

Is there something missed in the above fluentbit config file

Comment: 1) Why are you setting `kafka-broker:9092` twice along with `kafka-bootstrap:9092`? 2) We don't know if those hostnames are correct. Can you share any debugging steps you've done? Look at the logs for errors, not just your stdout? A daemonset doesn't know what namespace your Kafka address exists in. Maybe use a different address? https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/06/06/accessing-apache-kafka-in-strimzi-part-1-introduction#what_does_this_mean_for_kafka_on_kubernetes_

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Thanks for the response.

Both strimzi kafka and fluentbit are running in same namespace.
The actual hostname is example-kafka-bootstrap.fluentbit-demo.svc.cluster.local:9092
I haven't done any debugging steps other than stdout.

Actually I'm not sure whether to use kafka bootstrap or Broker URL for Brokers key in [OUTPUT].

Comment: Updated the configuration above.

Comment: Neither value you had provided would be correct, when the local server DNS will be `example-kafka-bootstrap.svc.local`. Regarding ports, without seeing your Strimzi config, it's hard to say... Do your edits work now? Have you tried to `kubectl exec` into the fluentbit pods and tried running Kafka commands / pinging your bootstrap service